# httpd server not reading rewrite conf

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, amazon-ec2, httpd.conf

I am using amazon ec2 machine with httpd installed. I want to do some redirection of urls. For this I have done:

- Enabled mod_rewrite module.
- AllowOverride All in httpd.conf file under Directory /var/www/html
- Created a .htaccess file in /var/www/html and wrote rewrite rules

The issue is that server is not even reading my .htaccess file.

Am I putting .htaccess file in wrong location.
I have tried copy pasting .htaccess in various locations but with no success.
I have also tried writing rules in httpd.conf itself instead of .htaccess but that also results me failure.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Put some nonsense in your root .htaccess - do you get a 500 error trying to load a page? If so, htaccess is being read, and the problem is with the rewrite rules or perhaps modules config. If not, then yeah, apache isn't reading the file. At least you'll know one way or the other

Comment: @Clive I have tried putting GARBAGE in .htaccess but no error appears.

Comment: To use redirections you just need. `Redirect/RedirectMatch from mod_alias` when these are simple redirections, and as for mod_rewrite you just need the module and the directive `RewriteEngine on` and define them in the appropiate context. `You DO NO NEED .htaccess`, in fact, if you can admin the server, it is better to disable it `AllowOverride none`. Your redirects/rewrites will be simpler and your server will be faster if you define them in Virtualhost context instead of per-dir.

Comment: @ezra-s I had defined Rewrite rules under VirtualHost as you mentioned, as follows 

`NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName http://www.example.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinte$
    RewriteRule ^post/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/staticfeed.php?id=$1 $
</VirtualHost>`

Now my website shows **Apache Test Page** instead. I googled the issue and found the solution stating to delete welcome.conf inside conf.d. So I had done that also. Now I see **index of/** page. Could you help me in this.

Comment: @arushijain Index of /, just means there is no index file such as index.html and you have Indexes on so it shows a directory listing

Comment: @ezra-s Actually I want to redirect `crawlers` (like facebook, twitter, google) to a different page (http://www.example.com/staticfeed.php) using rewrite rules. So, for this I was writing the above rules, which is not working for me. Can you pleas guide me on how should I go about implementing the crawler's redirect?